# Issue showing information on change event

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a combobox when that use onchange event.

When I select an option is not updating the span

Here is the information: http://jsfiddle.net/S5fbc/72/

```
<script>function change(){
var a1 = document.getElementById("a");
var b1 = document.getElementById("b");
var c1 = document.getElementById("c");
a1.innerHTML = b1.value;
}
</script>
<select id="trick"  onkeypress="change()">
  <option>Select Please</option>
  <option value="a">AAAAA</option>
  <option value="b">BBBBB</option>
  <option value="c">CCCCC</option>
</select>

<span id="a1">First Text</span>
<span id="b1">Second text</span>
<span id="c1">Third text</span>
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: What does this have to do with "prototype"???

Comment: You know the elements have ID's like `a1`, not `a` ?

Comment: I'm using prototype 1.6 and jquery-1.4.min in my real project that's what I need that please

Comment: @CarlitosMorales: You should first learn to utilize the DOM without them. Don't use them now. Never use them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ids of the spans you are trying to select are not `a`, `b`, `c`, but `a1`, `b1`, `c1`.

The element of which you want to access the `.value` is not `b1`, but the select element which has the id `trick`.

If you want to listen for a `change` event, you should not use `onkeypress`.

You seem to want

```
function change(){
    var trick = document.getElementById("trick"),
        els = {
            a: document.getElementById("a1"),
            b: document.getElementById("b1"),
            c: document.getElementById("c1")
        };
    for (var p in els)
        els[p].style.display = "none";
    var selected = trick.value;
    if (selected in els)
        els[selected].style.display = "";
}
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S5fbc/78/))

Comment: No, the span elements don't have `.value`s. What do you actually *want to do*? How should which span be updated, depending how on the value of the select element?

Comment: When I click on AAAA will show "First Text", when do click on BBBB will show "Second Text" and click on CCCC will show "Third Text"

Comment: All the options should be hide and when it changes will be inline http://jsfiddle.net/S5fbc/76/

Comment: Yes that's right... I checked your demo but is not showing the span  information when is selecting an option

Comment: It is showing the respective span when you have selected it? Isn't that what you wanted?